# Button on Widget and onUpdate

Tags: android, eclipse, widget

In a widget I've to set two different actions,
I've got a Widget.class and a WidgetConfig.class

onUpdate (then I will change the refresh rate from provider.xml) I've to call a function on WidgetConfig.class like WidgetConfig.routine(parameter1,parameter2)

On button_click I've to call another routine in WidgetConf.class like WidgetConf.routine2(parameter1,parameter2)

How could I call that routine from the widget Button?

Example:
Every X time the widget autoupdates (change color by returned function value)
Only on click the widget must call another function and then do an update

Comment: Solved by following my answer on this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824817/solved-android-widget-click-for-action-update-under-30-minutes-separate-ins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by following my answer on this post:
[SOLVED: Android Widget - Click for action, update under 30 minutes, separate instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824817/solved-android-widget-click-for-action-update-under-30-minutes-separate-ins)

Two different intent where called...

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple take a boolean variable and set true or false in one of the method u call if it is true call method1 else method2 and also change the value in the end of function declaration